# Unchecked Assignment Warning in JPA NativeQuery Get ResultList

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, spring-data-jpa

Code snippet:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<UserDevice> findAllUserDevices(Long userId) {
    return em.createNativeQuery(Sql.USER_DEVICE_GET_ALL_USER_DEVICE, UserDevice.class)
            .setParameter(1, userId)
            .getResultList();
}
```

While returning the result I am getting a warning of Unchecked Assignment, is there a way to remove this warning without using the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation

**Note:** I am already passing `UserDevice.class` while creating the query object, by this, I am able to remove this warning in `em.createQuery()` method but it does not help me in case of `em.createNativeQuery()`

Answer (score 0):

The getResultList returns the rawtype List which is why it's giving you that warning. Best way to ignore it is that SupressWarnings annotation.